# What's the right way for push json result to array in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want fetch a json api and push that result into an array:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Users(){

    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';
    let nodes = [];

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(j => {
        for( var i = 0; i <= j.results.length; i++ ){
            nodes.push(<li>{j.results[i].name.first}</li>);
        }
    });

    return(
            <ul>{nodes}</ul>
    );

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Users />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

But I have the following error in the console:

> TypeError: j.results[i] is undefined

How can I fixed this error?

Comment: The error is because of small comparison mistake, `i <= j.results.length;` should be `i < j.results.length;` but you structuring is not correct

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i edited , but i have not any result, so what's the right way for repeating json result in react ?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is `react` way of fixing this problem. Here is the solution of your problem:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(){
    console.log('here')
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const nodes = data.results;
        this.setState({nodes})
      })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.nodes.map(node => <li key={node.name.first} >{node.name.first}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Worked example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95686/). Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Users extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       nodes: []
     }
     this.load()
  }

  load() {
    const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5';
    return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(({results:nodes}) => this.setState({nodes}))
   }

   render() {
     let {nodes} = this.state
     return <ul>{nodes.map(({name:{first}}) => <li>{first}</li>)}</ul>
   }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(
     <Users />,
     document.getElementById('main')
 );
```